# Need to lookup values in excel even if its not an exact match or ends up with certain characters without putting data in asc/des order

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have an excel sheet where I need to lookup value even if the destination column is not an exact match or contains certain additional specific characters, without arranging the data in order.

[Look at a sample sheet here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35DgH.png)

Comment: Per your provided sample image, in cell F4 and copy down: `=VLOOKUP(E4&"-wu*",A:B,2,FALSE)`

Answer (score 0):

To vlookup without arranging the data in order, use Index/match instead of VLOOKUP.

The Match function allows you to add * as a wildcard to your search term; thus *pie would match apple_pie, and so would apple*.

General syntax is:

```
=INDEX('column of return values', MATCH('search term', 'column of search values', 0))
```

Note that we use 0 instead of 1 or -1... the other options enable "nearest" searching.

Make sure that the columns start and end on the same row!  When using tables, make sure that the headers aren't included!  (don't let the cell picker add [#All] to your table references.)

I said 'column' but this method can use rows, too, since MATCH passes an integer over to INDEX.